# Need help in building query to populate instance name

Tags: sql

I am new to sql and building query,I have built the logic for most of the scenarios but got stuck with one scenario.Example :

If we have data like below how can I populate instance name and fetch it based on that.

Input :

| id | proj_id | project_name | template_type | tech_name | instance_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000 | 11111 | test | jenkins | greenplum | mnc |
| 00001 | 11111 | test | jenkins | teradata |  |
| 00002 | 11112 | test1 | db | streamset | abc |

So my query is I need to fetch the data where tech_name=teradata and instance name=mnc as the project id and template type of first and second record is same(11111 and jenkins) so we can assign same instance name to 2nd record i.e mnc and need to fetch then based on teradata and mnc it should fetch second row using sql.I am stuck with this one.I have tried creating the query something like this but its not working

```
where 
t1.instance_name=(
  select max(instance_name )
  FROM test.table t2 
  where t2.project_id=t1.project_id)
```

Comment: You have tagged two completely different DBMS products, why?

Comment: What's your expected output? Providing that with some more clear language, with some punctuation, on why that's the result you expect would do a great deal. Don't mean to be snarky, but I read that slowly a few times and I'm not sure.

Comment: I removed the various dbms you tagged , only tag the database you are using.

Comment: @error_2646 - Output is I need to write query so that I can fetch second record base on technology name = Teradata and instance name =mnc....as you see the first record instance name is there and in second record it's not there so if template type and project I'd is same we can use the one where instance name is present.

Comment: That comment doesn't make things any clearer. You are saying that you "want to fetch second record based on technology name = Teradata". Well, there's only one record with that name in your sample data. There is no second record with that name. I can guess as what you really want. Does technology name really matter here? Don't you simply want to populate the instance name for a matched Project and Template? Why do you keep mentioning technology name?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm understanding the request.

Depends on how general you want this to be. If it's really just Teradata and mnc to factor in doesn't need to be fancy.

```
with projects_with_teradata_mnc as (
    select distinct
           proj_id,
           template_type
      from your_table
     where tech_name = 'teradata'
       and instance_name = 'mnc'
    )
select <fields>,
       coalesce(yt.instance_name, 'mnc') as instance_name
  from your_table yt
  left
  join projects_with_teradata_mnc ptm
    on yt.proj_id = ptm.proj_id
   and yt.template_type = ptm.template_type
```

If you want it generalized, where null values of instance_name will be filled with a non-null value with the same proj_id and template.

This just selects the max alphabetically, if you want a precedence you'd need to specify a rule.

```
with instance_name_overrides as (
    select proj_id,
           template_type,
           max(instance_name) as alpha_max_instance_name
      from your_table
     where instance_name is not null
     group
        by proj_id,
           template_type
    )
select <fields>,
       coalesce(yt.instance_name, ino.alpha_max_instance_name) as instance_name
  from your_table yt
  left
  join instance_name_overrides ino
    on yt.proj_id = ino.proj_id
   and yt.template_type = ino.template_type
```

Comment: I think the 2nd query looks like what the OP is likely trying to do, with the possible addition of adding a where clause such as `where yt.tech_name = 'teradata' and coalesce(yt.instance_name, ino.alpha_max_instance_name) = 'mnc'` for returning just the one row. But it's tough to discern exactly what the OP wants.